# C++ delete pointer when referencing to a variable

Tags: c++, pointers

I do not quite understand about using the pointer in C++. My example code and question are below:

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr1, *ptr2;
    int val1, val2;
    ptr1 = new int;
    val1 = 45;
    ptr1 = &val1;
    ptr2 = ptr1;
    cout << *ptr2;
    delete ptr1; //Crashed
}
```

The reason why it got runtime error because I tried to delete the address of val1. So what should I do to delete the ptr1 and ptr2?

Comment: You don't `delete` something that was not `new`'d. And `ptr1 = &val1;` reassigns `ptr1` to another value (the address of `val1`) which was not `new`'d, so you cannot delete it, and should not attempt to. This also means that the `new int;` allocation will be a memory leak, since it never gets `delete`'d.

Comment: @dxiv so basically the memory leak happens only when I am using new int. Am I correct? so in the above case, I do not have to delete the ptr1 and ptr2 because it references the existing variable that will not cause a memory leak. Am I correct on this too?

Comment: That's correct. Which still leaves the memory leak to fix, as explained in one of the answers below.

Comment: @dxiv thank you so much for your explanation. I got it now. appreciate that.

Comment: @laughing You can only delete blocks of memory that you allocated. Since `ptr1` and `ptr2` are variables, they are not things that you might delete. You don't "delete a pointer", you delete the block of memory that a pointer points to, if it points to a block of memory you need to delete.

Comment: To store value of `val1` in `ptr1`, change your line to `*ptr1 = val1;` and then `delete ptr1` will not crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may only pass to `delete` something you got from `new`. You didn't save the value you got from `new` since you modified `ptr1` to contain `&val1`. So you cannot `delete` it and thus your code has a memory leak. You can fix it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    int val1, val2;
    ptr1 = new int;
    ptr3 = ptr1; // save the value we got from new so we can delete it later
    val1 = 45;
    ptr1 = &val1; // ptr1 no longer contains the value we got from new
    ptr2 = ptr1; // ptr2 and ptr1 both contain &val1 now
    cout << *ptr2;
    delete ptr3; // pass the value we got from new to delete
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because val1 is not in heap memory.

Comment: and as you did ptr1 = &val1, any pointer variable does not refer 'new' data so your code generated memory leak.

Comment: thank you for your commence. Those help me a lot. Now I know where my code generates memory leaks.